Upgrading Sharepoint 2019 to Sharepoint Subscription Edition
I want to migrate sharepoint 2019 to sharepoint subscription edition. In the Microsoft documentation for database detach method of migration, it is written that all databases must be of version 16.0.4351.1000 or higher. However, sharepoint subscription edition supports SQL Server 2019 with CU 5 or higher. So, my Sharepoint Subscription Edition environment and my Sharepoint 2019 environment is on SQL Server 2019. So, how can I perform the migration? When I try to follow the steps written in upgrade instructions, the step on service application (UPS) stalls. The following commands stays running for ever and doesn't throw any error.
New-SPProfileServiceApplication -Name '<UserProfileApplicationName>' -ApplicationPool $applicationPool -ProfileDBName '<ProfileDBName>' -SocialDBName '<SocialDBName>' -ProfileSyncDBName '<SyncDBName>'

Database version requirements for Subscription edition clearly states that it supports SQL Server 2019 CU5 and above as stated here. Can you please advise how can I perform the migration in such case?

sharepoint subscription edition supports Sharepoint 2019 with CU 5 or higher, do you mean SQL Server 2019 with CU 5?

Yes, SQL Server 2019 with CU 5, sorry.

I managed to solve this issue. I was taking the DB backup using the source farm admin user and restoring the DB in the destination server using the destination farm admin user. I added the destination farm admin user as sysadmin and db_owner in the source farm database server and used that login to take the backup. It worked in this way.
